# Auto logout if there is any more then 1 session per user at a time in Laravel 5.4

Tags: sql, laravel-5

I am trying to do auto logout when more then one session occurs. That's mean if there is a session loged in for a user, that user can not log in from others at a time. How can I do that. Which file should make change? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you currently keeping track of any login information?

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 5.2 after executing the `make:auth` command you can create the method:`public function authenticated(Request $request,User $user)` in the `AuthController.php` and in that method you can do what you want after login. For a single session per user we add to the AuthController at top:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Auth;
```

And add the function:

```
public function authenticated(Request $request,User $user){
    $previous_session = $user->session_id;

    if ($previous_session) {
        \Session::getHandler()->destroy($previous_session);
    }

    Auth::user()->session_id = \Session::getId();
    Auth::user()->save();
    return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
}
```

Don't forget to add the migration for altering your users table with the session_id column.